# How Do I Filter Spreadsheet Data Based On Another Column?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to filter out a spreadsheet that will be used for tracking commission payments. There are 3 milestone payments per customer. I am trying to build a separate section that only includes the customer's first and last name, as well as any milestone payment that has a pay date in the column next to it.

I built a spreadsheet to help demonstrate what I am trying to do with some examples of my filters that I am failing at.

Could a spreadsheet wizard take a look and see if what I am trying to accomplish is even possible?

Either EXCEL or Google Sheets is acceptable.

Link to test sheet:
[Link to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KP2c_coa-8Ox5wEMOMnwQkdpQz2gtM_a9_I6kQ30q1E/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Screenshot of spreadsheet]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IF(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(MONTH(
 FILTER(A35:1000, REGEXMATCH(A34:34, "Pay Date.+")))=10, 1, )),,9^9)))="",, A35:B1000), IF(MONTH(
 FILTER(A35:1000, REGEXMATCH(A34:34, "Pay Date.+")))=10,
 FILTER(A35:1000, REGEXMATCH(A34:34, "Milestone.+")), )}, 
 "where Col1 is not null"))
```

[image]

---

### update

to include year use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IF(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF((MONTH(
 FILTER(A35:1000, REGEXMATCH(A34:34, "Pay Date.+")))=10)*(YEAR(
 FILTER(A35:1000, REGEXMATCH(A34:34, "Pay Date.+")))=2021), 1, )),,9^9)))="",, A35:B1000), IF((MONTH(
 FILTER(A35:1000, REGEXMATCH(A34:34, "Pay Date.+")))=10)*(YEAR(
 FILTER(A35:1000, REGEXMATCH(A34:34, "Pay Date.+")))=2021),
 FILTER(A35:1000, REGEXMATCH(A34:34, "Milestone.+")), )}, 
 "where Col1 is not null"))
```

Comment: Oh wow. I think you got it. If possible, can you tweak the formula to check the year as well. So in this case, month = 10 and year = 2021? I will need to differentiate in a few months when 2022 rolls along. So Ill be checking month and year to pull the right customers. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mike sure, answer updated...

Comment: Thank you very much. I've been struggling with this for a couple days. You rock!